# Need to assign width to element by taking value from attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have this **HTML** code:

```
<div class="skills">
    <div class="skill">
        <span>Photoshop</span>
        <div class="bar" data-percent="80">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="skill">
        <span>Illustrator</span>
        <div class="bar" data-percent="20">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="skill">
        <span>Wordpress</span>
        <div class="bar" data-percent="30">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="skill">
        <span>Joomla</span>
        <div class="bar" data-percent="65">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this **jQuery** code:

```
var width = $('.bar').attr('data-percent');
$('.bar > div').css('width', width + "%");
```

Right now it's getting the first `.bar's` value of the data-percent attribute, e.g. 40, and passing it as a **CSS** style, e.g. `width: 40%`, but it's taking the first .bar's attribute only, and applying the same width to all the other elements. I want it to take the attribute for each of them, and assign their widths to each of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('.bar > div').css('width', function(){
    return $(this).parent().data('percent') + '%'
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vX7w4/)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `.each` function to handle each `.bar` element, and you can use jquery's .data function to get data-* attributes instead of the `.attr` function

```
$('.bar').each(function() {
   var width = $(this).data("percent");
   $(this).find('div').css("width",width+"%");
});
```

Comment: You can also do it like this way to find an element in the container element. `$("div", this).method();`

Answer (score 1):

replace your jQuery code on:

```
$('.bar > div').css('width', function(){
    return $(this).parent().data('percent') + '%'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.bar').each(function() {
var width = $(this).data("percent");
$(this).find('div').css("width",width+"%");
});
```